# How to make a Form submit work on mobile?

Tags: html, vue.js, web

I have a form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="login">
  <input
    type="email"
    v-model="email"
    class="form-control"
    name="email"
    placeholder="email"
  />
  <input
    type="password"
    class="form-control"
    name="password"
    v-model="password"
    placeholder="password"
  />
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

This works perfecly on the desktop browsers, but when trying to use the Login button on mobile devices, nothing seems to happen.

Here is the method login:

```
login() {
  this.$store
  .dispatch("login", {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
  })
  .then(() => {
    this.$router.push("/dashboard");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

If anyone can please help me with this.

Comment: If using Chrome on Android, you can try remote debugging ~ https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Comment: sadly I am using ios